# How do I access an array within cellForRowAtIndexPath without getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uitableview

I have a bug that is driving me crazy. I have an `NSArray` called questions. The array is being populated by a JSON response. I'm trying to use it to populate the table view.

in my header file I'm defining questions like this

```
@interface OneViewController : UITableViewController <MBProgressHUDDelegate> {
    NSArray *questions;
    MBProgressHUD *HUD;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *questions;
```

and in my implementation, im instantiating it like this

```
@synthesize questions;
```

when the view loads, I'm calling this function that pings my JSON service

```
- (void) pullQuestions {
    NSMutableDictionary *viewParams = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [viewParams setValue:@"questions" forKey:@"view"];
    [PythonView viewGet:viewParams success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        questions = responseObject;
        NSLog(@"Qestions: %@", responseObject);
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        [HUD hide:YES];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        //ALog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];
}
```

When I get a response, I trace out the response object, it is a properly formated JSON response.

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"VideoFeedCell";
        NSInteger count = [questions count];
        NSLog(@"Count: %i", count);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            NSString* body = [questions objectAtIndex:i];
            NSLog(@"Object: %@", body);
        }
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"VideoFeedCell" owner:self options:nil];
        // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];   
    }
    return cell;
}
```

So as I loop through this, questions count is 4 and the first object in the array is traced out (as null). The second time it tries to execute the for loop, I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. it's almost like the questions array just disappears. The strangest pat is I use almost the exact same code in another project and it works fine. I even tested it with the same JSON service that I used in the other project (so I know it's not malformed or something) and I still get this error.I'm really stuck, I fell like it must have to do either with saving the JSON response as an Array or something strange with the array it's self being released.

Comment: Show how `questions` is populated.  If it's a property, show the property declaration.

Comment: I updated it so that the declaration and population of questions is more clear

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot, yes the problem was that ARC was not enabled, and in the other project it was, sorry to wast ever ones time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you aren't using ARC, I suspect the problem is that you are assigning the `responseObject` directly to the `questions` instance variable rather than through the property.  This means that you aren't taking ownership of the `responseObject` and it is getting released when the autorelease pool is flushed.

Try changing:

```
questions = responseObject;
```

to:

```
questions = [responseObject retain];
```

or:

```
self.questions = responseObject;
```

and see if that fixes things.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was related to ARC. I started with some old boiler plate code ( a tabbed nav project I had built a while back). and tried to retrofit it. I did not pay attention to the fact that one project wars ARC and one was not.